# mysql database logic for messages and removing messages

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently stuck with my logic.

I have created a database table for snedimg messages

table `messages` looks like this

```
id | sender_id | reciver_id | msg                      | send_date |
1  | 2         |  6         | hello there i am testing | 2013-01-15
```

So what i am totally stuck with is the removing the message logic.
The problem what i dont understand how to solve is, lets say `user` with the `id 6` gets the message, and removes it by id, that way who sent the message wont be able to see it either.

So i am a bit lost at this, if someone could give me a hint on a logic i would really be happy

**EDIT WITH MORE EXPLAINED DETAILS**

So the problem is

```
id | sender_id | reciver_id | msg                      | send_date |
1  | 2         |  6         | hello there i am testing | 2013-01-15
```

this is the table. User recives the message, reads it, and for some reason wants to remove it.

Probmel is the `DELETE LOGIC`, i know how to delete rows, what i dont know is how to solve the problem if the reciver deletes the message, the sender will be able to see it un the he/she deletes it.

For example on facebook they use archive instead of delete, this is the logic what i dont understand

Comment: the message should be duplicated, add column type = ENUM('sent','received')

Comment: What about adding two columns `active_for_sender` and `active_for_reciver` then just put a non-zero for active and a 0 for not active  or "deleted"

Comment: Not enough clear for me. Why you want to remove the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the reciver or sender id to -1 on deletion and have a check afterwards if both are -1 (or would be -1) delete that row.

e.g.

```
on deletion by reciver:
if ($sender_id == -1) {
  $query = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE id=$id";
} else {
  $query = mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET reciver_id=-1 WHERE id=$id";
}
mysql_query($query)
```

That way it would be still availabe until both delete it

**Edit:**
Just as additional thought for that solution:
You could set both to -1 instead of deleting it on the second user deletion so you got a kind of archive and delete too old ones by a cronjob.

Answer (score 1):

if you want `sender` see the message even after it's deleted by the `receiver`, you can use the following logic:

1. Add a new column to your table named `deleted`, where values `1` means the message has been deleted, and `0` means it's not deleted yet.
2. If this is the `receiver` try to see their messages: `WHERE deleted = 0`
3. If this is the `sender` simply show all; don't use the above `WHERE` clause.
4. for removing the message, in your PHP delete function first check the value of `deleted`, if it is `1` you can permanently delete the row from your table using SQL `DELETE`. Otherwise, you just need to update the value of `deleted` column to `1`